# Fetching weather data from API

Tags: json, flutter, api, http, dart

I'm having a hard time trying to fetch data from this API. I've looked at a lot of answers on stack overflow but they don't answer my problem. This is my code and I can't find anything wrong with it.

```
var temp;

getWeather() async {
http.Response response = await http.get(
  Uri.parse(
    "https://api.tomorrow.io/v4/timelines?location=-73.98529171943665,40.75872069597532&fields=temperature&timesteps=1h&units=imperial&apikey=(API_KEY)",
  ),
);
var results = json.decode(response.body);
print(results);
setState(() {
  this.temp = results['data']['timelines']['0']['intervals']['0']['values']
      ['Temperature'];
});
 print(this.temp);
}

@override
void initState() {
 super.initState();
 this.getWeather();
}
```

This is the json from the api that im try to get the data from. i trying to get the first temperature data.

```
{

"data": {
    "timelines": [
        {
            "timestep": "1h",
            "startTime": "2021-07-20T01:00:00Z",
            "endTime": "2021-07-24T13:00:00Z",
            "intervals": [
                {
                    "startTime": "2021-07-20T01:00:00Z",
                    "values": {
                        "temperature": -52.1
                    }
                },
                {
                    "startTime": "2021-07-20T02:00:00Z",
                    "values": {
                        "temperature": -51.81
                    }
                },
                {
                    "startTime": "2021-07-20T03:00:00Z",
                    "values": {
                        "temperature": -51.62
                    }
                },
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
 }

}
```

Thank you to anyone that answered my dumb question.

Comment: BUT... what's the error message you get?

Comment: The call is wrong, you should use this `results['data']['timelines'][0]['intervals'][0]['values']['temperature']`, otherwise you get a null value. I made a little code below.

Comment: Performing hot restart...                                               
Restarted application in 862ms.
flutter: <api json>
flutter: null

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:wnetworking/wnetworking.dart';

typedef JMap = Map<String, dynamic>;

class TomorrowIO {
  static const _apiKey = '1234567890';
  static const _base = 'https://api.tomorrow.io/v4';

  static FutureOr<void> retrieveTimelines({required double latitude, required double longitude}) async {
    final url = '$_base/timelines?location=$latitude,$longitude&fields=temperature&timesteps=1h&units=metric&apikey=$_apiKey';
    List? result;
    
    stdout.write('Retrieving timelines... ');
    await HttpReqService.getJson<JMap>(url)
      .then((response) {
        if (response != null) {
          result = response['data']['timelines'] as List;
        }
      })
      .whenComplete(() {
        print('done.\n');
        print(result![0]['intervals'][0]['values']['temperature']);
      });
  }
}

void main(List<String> args) async {
  await TomorrowIO.retrieveTimelines(latitude: -73.98529171943665, longitude: 40.75872069597532);
  print('\nJob done!');
}
```

Result:

```
Retrieving timelines... done.

-52.1

Job done!
```

You can replace `wnetworking` package (and code) with `http`.